# Parsing nested JSON without using getJSON()

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I know there are a hundred "parse json" questions already out there - but I couldn't find one with a solution that matched my own situation.

I receive JSON similar to this:

```
{    
"parent:array": [
    {
        "child:value": "test1",
        "child:array": [
            {
                "child:subvalue": "test3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "child:value": "test2",
        "child:array": [
            {
                "child:subvalue": "test4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I can access `child:value` by doing the following (where `response` is the JSON):

```
var parameters = response['parent:array'];
$.each(parameters, function (idx, data) {
    var childValue = data['child:value'];
});
```

However, I haven't been able to retrieve `child:subvalue` yet. Can it be done as part of the `each`?

I tried the following approaches without success:

```
response['parent:array']['child:array']
```

and...

```
var childSubvalue = data['child:array']['child:subvalue'];
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.  `"child:array"` has a close `}` where it should have a close `]`.

Comment: did you try: `"child:array.child:subvalue"` ?

Comment: @blurfus: You need to use `[]` because of the `:`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That was a mistype, thanks for the correction.

Comment: your json is still not valid. the comma after "test3" needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once your json is valid:

```
$.each(parameters, function (idx, data) {
    var childValue = data['child:value'], childArray = data['child:array'];
    $.each(childArray, function(i, d) {
        alert(d['child:subvalue']);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbsAx/2/)

Answer (score 2):

`"child:array"` is an array, so you need to give an index to select, like so:

```
var childSubvalue = data['child:array'][0]['child:subvalue'];
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Do you have an idea how I could incorporate that into a loop? Where [0] would be [i]? For example I could add that line to the `each` I defined in the question - but I would only get the first `child:subvalue` as `parent:array` has a size of '1'.

Comment: Yeah, just add another loop in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the outer and inner arrays with array.forEach;

```
var json = {    
"parent:array": [
    {
        "child:value": "test1",
        "child:array": [
            {
                "child:subvalue": "test3",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "child:value": "test2",
        "child:array": [
            {
                "child:subvalue": "test4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

json["parent:array"].forEach(function(parent) {
    console.log(parent["child:value"]);
    parent["child:array"].forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child["child:subvalue"]);
    });
});
```